# Request a file and transfer file using java socket

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer, lan

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         



    try{
            Socket socket = new Socket(jTextField1.getText(), 15123);
    OutputStream oStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    String name = jTextField2.getText();
            DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(oStream);
              d.writeUTF(name);

    oStream.flush();
    oStream.close();

}catch(IOException e){
}
}
```

---

```
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new testGUI().setVisible(true);


    try {

         ServerSocket serverSocket3 = new ServerSocket(15123);
        Socket socket3 = serverSocket3.accept();
        InputStream iStream3 = socket3.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream d3 = new DataInputStream(iStream3);
        InetAddress ip = socket3.getInetAddress();
        String t = d3.readUTF();

        Socket socket1 = new Socket(ip.toString(), 3333);
        OutputStream oStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(socket1.getOutputStream());



        File folder = new File("C:");

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){


        String filename = listOfFiles[i].getName();

                String fi = d3.toString();
        String[] fn = fi.split("\\.");

        if(filename.startsWith(fn[0]) && listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith(fn[1])){

                     DataOutputStream d1 = new DataOutputStream(oStream1);
                     d1.writeUTF(d3.toString());

                     File file1 = new File(folder.toString()+"/"+filename);
                     InputStream iStream1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
                      byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file1.length()];
        for (int readCount = iStream1.read(buffer); readCount != -1; readCount = iStream1.read(buffer)) {
            oStream1.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }
        oStream1.flush();
        oStream1.close();
        iStream1.close();

        }
    }


    } catch (IOException e) {

    }




        }


    });


    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket1 = new ServerSocket(3333);
        Socket socket1 = serverSocket1.accept();
       InetAddress ip = socket1.getInetAddress();
        InputStream iStream1 = socket1.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(iStream1);

        FileOutputStream oStream1 = new FileOutputStream(d.readUTF());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

        int count;
        while ((count = iStream1.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            oStream1.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        oStream1.flush();
        oStream1.getFD().sync();
        oStream1.close();
        iStream1.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File recived"+ip.toString(), "Notification", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (IOException e) {

}
}
```

problems- (netbean code)

1)Not load GUI
2)not sending request file to another pc.

my task is; If some one request a file from someone, it search form shared location(per defined) and get the file and send it back to the requester.

need a help

Comment: I removed ,

ServerSocket serverSocket3 = new ServerSocket(15123);
            Socket socket3 = serverSocket3.accept();
            InputStream iStream3 = socket3.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream d3 = new DataInputStream(iStream3);
            InetAddress ip = socket3.getInetAddress();
            String t = d3.readUTF();

these lines its load GUI. but not works. Why??

Comment: Please clean up formatting because it's hard to read your code. Also, your code is quite long. Please, shorten it to ~20 lines (if you know where the error is) or provide the full application code (if you expect someone to compile and debug it). I think there are two separate applications? Please clarify. Which GUI is not loaded? Your code doesn't contain anything about GUI.

Comment: This is a one program its include receiver part and transfer part together..... GUI is auto generated code by netbeans.